# How to pass dynamic parameters to filter a function in Pyspark?

Tags: function, filter, pyspark, parameter-passing

*Hi everyone*

*I have several queries to develop and I thought automating the whole process with a function , the only problem is that the whole structure is practically the same , there are two things that do change , the first one is the ***filter*** & the second one is the creation of the ***Group_Service*** Column*

*For example for the first query I have a filter on the ***Service*** Column where f.col("Service").like("% New Bank ROME%") & the ***Group_Service*** column gets created as follows :
.withColumn('group_service', f.lit("ROME Services").cast("string"))*

*For the second query I have a filter on the ***Service*** Column where f.col("Service").like("% New Bank BERLIN%") & the ***Group_Service*** column gets created as follows :
.withColumn('group_service', f.lit("BERLIN Services").cast("string"))*

*And in some cases the filter and the ***Group_Service*** column do not even exist ,so the query would not include those two.*

Here's my code :

```
def Query(df):
    df_1 = df.filter(df.customer.like('IT - ROME%') 
                & (f.col("day") > datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
        & (df.service.like('% New Bank ROME%')))\
                .select("day" , "customer" , "availability" ,  f.month(f.col("day")).cast("string").alias("month"))\
                .select("day" , "month" , "availability"  , "customer" ,  f.year(f.col("day")).cast("string").alias("year"))\
                .withColumn('group_service', f.lit("ROME Services").cast("string"))\
                .withColumn("year_month_s", f.when((f.col("month") == "10") | (f.col("month") == "11") | (f.col("month") == "12") , 
                f.concat(f.col("year"), f.lit(" "),f.col("month")))
                .otherwise( f.concat(f.col("year"), f.lit(" 0"),f.col("month")))
                ).distinct()\
                .withColumn("customer", f.when(f.col('customer').like('IT - ROME%')
                , 'IT - ROME - BANK'))\
```

*So , I was wondering how I may "automate" the whole process with additional dynamic parameters , any help would be greatly appreciated , thank you*

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the location with format strings:

```
def Query(df, location, service):
    df_1 = df.filter(df.customer.like(f'IT - {location}%') 
                     & (f.col("day") > datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
    if service:
        df_1 = df_1 & (df.service.like(f'% New Bank {location}%')))\
                .select("day" , "customer" , "availability" ,  f.month(f.col("day")).cast("string").alias("month"))\
                .select("day" , "month" , "availability"  , "customer" ,  f.year(f.col("day")).cast("string").alias("year"))\
                .withColumn('group_service', f.lit(f"{location} Services").cast("string"))\
                .withColumn("year_month_s", f.when((f.col("month") == "10") | (f.col("month") == "11") | (f.col("month") == "12") , 
                f.concat(f.col("year"), f.lit(" "),f.col("month")))
                .otherwise( f.concat(f.col("year"), f.lit(" 0"),f.col("month")))
                ).distinct()\
                .withColumn("customer", f.when(f.col('customer').like(f'IT - {location}%')
                , f'IT - {location} - BANK'))
```

Comment: Thank you , but what if my query doesn't have the condition on the Service , will it still be working ? , thank you again